# Preserve formatting of text using letterings.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to preserve formatting (e.g. bold, italic) of text when using the letterings.js plugin?  I am using the "word" wrapping function (https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/wiki/Wrapping-words-with-lettering%28%27words%27%29) and it seems to destroy any formatting made of the text.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="text-block">This is a <i>sentence</i> <b>with <i>formatting</i></b>.</div>
```

After using letterings.js, it turns into:

```
<div class="text-block">
   <span class="word1">This</span>
   <span class="word2">is</span>
   <span class="word3">a</span>
   <span class="word4">sentence</span>
   <span class="word5">with</span>
   <span class="word6">formatting.</span>
</div>
```

This is the function I'm using in jQuery:

```
$('.text-block').lettering('words');
```

I've found that I can preserve bold or italic (unfortunately not both) doing this:

```
$('.text-block b').lettering('words');
```

**-OR-**

```
$('.text-block i').lettering('words');
```

You can't use both ( i.e. `$('.text-block b,.text-block i')` ) at the same time.

If it's not possible with letterings.js, is there another plugin or method to wrap each word in spans but preserve the formatting?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the method in line 15 from .text() to .html(), you can use

```
$('.text-block').lettering('words');
```

as is and it will not strip the tags.

Use this link to get the source:

https://gist.github.com/klatchbaldar/6956474